# HttpClient Post photo WITH message to Facebook Graph

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

**Issue**

I am trying to upload a photo to the Facebook API WITH a message.

**Code Snippet - Upload**

```
        requestUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos?access_token=MyAccessToken"

        var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "\"files\"",
            FileName = "\"image.jpg\""
        };
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg"); 
        var messageContent = new StringContent("message=HelloWorld");
        var resultJson = webRequestClient.Post(requestUri, new MultipartFormDataContent()
        {
            messageContent,
            streamContent, 
        });
```

**Code - webRequestClient**

```
    public string Post(string uri, HttpContent postData)
    {
        return PostAsync(uri, postData).Result;
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        string resultStream;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            resultStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return resultStream;
    }
```

**Notes**

- If I remove the "messageContent" : It uploads he picture
- If I use MultipartContent : It uploads the picture but ignores my "message"
- Don't bother for now why I don't do use the async functionality
- When it fails I get "bad" requests
- When I append the "message=helloworld" in the requestUri, it works, but that isn't the most flexible solution for in my architecture to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it will solve you problem, either you have to send the image via stream then you don't need to tell that the type is "image/jpeg" explicitly.

```
protected async void TakePictureAndUpload()
{
    var ui = new CameraCaptureUI();
    var file = await ui.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    if (file != null)
    {    
        byte[] myPicArray = await GetPhotoBytesAsync(file);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourdomainname.com");

        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(myPicArray);
        form.Add(content, "media", "filename.jpg");
        content = new StringContent("my-username");
        form.Add(content, "username");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("directory/my-site.php", form);
     }
}
public async Task<byte[]> GetPhotoBytesAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);

    byte[] pixels = new byte[fileStream.Size];
    reader.ReadBytes(pixels);
    return pixels;
}
```